# RMI with SSL: Failed handshake

Tags: java, ssl, client-server, rmi

I'm writing a Client Server application with RMI and I want to secure the traffic between Client and Server. I want to use the `SslRMIClientSocketFactory` and `SslRMIServerSocketFactory` for this.

I've created a keypair for the Client and for the Server (`client.private` and `server.private`) and also a certificate for the Client and for the Server (`client.public` and `server.public`).

I think I'm correctly adding the keypair to the keystore and the certificate to the truststore. **I only use the custom Socket Factory's when exporting my objects, not when I'm creating the RMI Registry.** Here's my code:

**Server:**

```
public class Server implements ServerProtocol {
    public Server() {
        super();
        SecureRandom sr = new SecureRandom();
        sr.nextInt();

        KeyStore clientKeyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
        FileInputStream client = new FileInputStream("src/client.public");
        String passphrase = //
        clientKeyStore.load(client, passphrase.toCharArray());
        client.close();

        KeyStore serverKeyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
        FileInputStream server = new FileInputStream("src/server.private");
        String password = //
        serverKeyStore.load(server, password.toCharArray());
        server.close();

        TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
        tmf.init(clientKeyStore);

        KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
        kmf.init(serverKeyStore, password.toCharArray());

        SSLContext SSLC = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        SSLC.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), tmf.getTrustManagers(), sr);

        SslRMIClientSocketFactory csf = new SslRMIClientSocketFactory();
        SslRMIServerSocketFactory ssf = new SslRMIServerSocketFactory(null, null, true);

        LocateRegistry.createRegistry(2020).rebind("server", this);
        UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(this, 2020, csf, ssf);
    }

    public void sayHello() {
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
}
```

**Client:**

```
public class Client implements ClientProtocol {

    public Client() {
        SecureRandom sr = new SecureRandom();
        sr.nextInt();

        KeyStore serverKeyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
        FileInputStream server = new FileInputStream("src/server.public");
        String passphrase = //
        serverKeyStore.load(server, passphrase.toCharArray());
        server.close();

        KeyStore clientKeyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
        FileInputStream client = new FileInputStream("src/client.private");
        String password = //
        clientKeyStore.load(client, password.toCharArray());
        client.close();

        TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
        tmf.init(serverKeyStore);

        KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
        kmf.init(clientKeyStore, password.toCharArray());

        SSLContext SSLC = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        SSLC.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), tmf.getTrustManagers(), sr);

        SslRMIClientSocketFactory csf = new SslRMIClientSocketFactory();
        SslRMIServerSocketFactory ssf = new SslRMIServerSocketFactory(null, null, true);

        Registry reg = LocateRegistry.getRegistry("localhost", 2020);
        serverStub = (ServerService) reg.lookup("server");
        stub = (ClientService) UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(this, 2020, csf, ssf);

        serverStub.sayHello();
    }
}
```

When I run this, I get the following error message:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:174)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:136)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:1822)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1004)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1188)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:654)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:100)
at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:65)
at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:123)
at java.io.DataOutputStream.flush(DataOutputStream.java:106)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:211)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:184)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:110)
at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:178)
at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:132)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.sayHello(Unknown Source)
at project.Client.<init>(Client.java:100)
at project.Client.main(Client.java:785)
```

I used the following commands to create the keys, export and import them:

```
keytool -genkey -alias clientprivate -keystore client.private -storetype JKS -keyalg rsa -storepass * -keypass * -validity 360
keytool -genkey -alias serverprivate -keystore server.private -storetype JKS -keyalg rsa -storepass * -keypass * -validity 360

keytool -export -alias clientprivate -keystore client.private -file temp.key -storepass *
keytool -import -noprompt -alias clientpublic -keystore client.public -file temp.key -storepass *

keytool -export -alias serverprivate -keystore server.private -file temp.key -storepass *
keytool -import -noprompt -alias serverpublic -keystore server.public -file temp.key -storepass *
```

Do I need to configure something else to make this work? Something in Eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this by avoiding the build-in Java classes `SslRMIClientSocketFactory` and `SslRMIServerSocketFactory` and creating my own classes which implement the `RMIClientSocketFactory` and `RMIServerSocketFactory` interfaces.

**RMIClientSocketFactory**

```
public class MyClientSocketFactory implements RMIClientSocketFactory, Serializable {

    public MyClientSocketFactory() {}

    public Socket createSocket(String host, int port) {

        SecureRandom sr = new SecureRandom();
        sr.nextInt();

        KeyStore serverKeyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
        FileInputStream server = new FileInputStream("src/server.public");
        String passphrase = //
        serverKeyStore.load(server, passphrase.toCharArray());
        server.close();

        KeyStore clientKeyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
        FileInputStream client = new FileInputStream("src/client.private");
        String password = //
        clientKeyStore.load(client, password.toCharArray());
        client.close();

        TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
        tmf.init(serverKeyStore);

        KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
        kmf.init(clientKeyStore, password.toCharArray());

        SSLContext SSLC = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        SSLC.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), tmf.getTrustManagers(), sr);

        SSLSocketFactory sf = SSLC.getSocketFactory();
        SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket) sf.createSocket(host, port);

        return socket;
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        return getClass().hashCode();
    }

    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == this) {
            return true;
        } else if (obj == null || getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

**RMIServerSocketFactory**

```
public class MyServerSocketFactory implements RMIClientSocketFactory, Serializable {

    public MyServerSocketFactory() {}

    public Socket createSocket(String host, int port) {

        SecureRandom sr = new SecureRandom();
        sr.nextInt();

        KeyStore clientKeyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
        FileInputStream client = new FileInputStream("src/client.public");
        String passphrase = //
        clientKeyStore.load(client, passphrase.toCharArray());
        client.close();

        KeyStore serverKeyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
        FileInputStream server = new FileInputStream("src/server.private");
        String password = //
        serverKeyStore.load(server, password.toCharArray());
        server.close();

        TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
        tmf.init(serverKeyStore);

        KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
        kmf.init(clientKeyStore, password.toCharArray());

        SSLContext SSLC = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        SSLC.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), tmf.getTrustManagers(), sr);

        SSLServerSocketFactory sf = SSLC.getServerSocketFactory();
        SSLServerSocket socket = (SSLServerSocket) sf.createServerSocket(host, port);

        return socket;
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        return getClass().hashCode();
    }

    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == this) {
            return true;
        } else if (obj == null || getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're creating the Registry with SSL socket factories but you're not supplying a socket  factory to getRegistry().

Comment: Post the rest of the stack trace. Edit it into your question. At a minimum you need to configure a keystore in the server.

Comment: I've posted the full stack trace. What is a keystore, why do I need this and how do I configure it?

Comment: You need to now take a good look at the JSSE Reference Guide. You need a server certificate and keypair in the keystore and you need to either get it signed by a CA or imported into the client truststore.

Comment: Yes I have, I will put the commands that I used in the question

Comment: Please run your server with -Djava.rmi.server.logCalls=true and edit the results into your question.

Comment: Does it matter where to certificates and keypairs are in the file system??

Comment: Not as long as they are found.

Comment: I **don't** get a `FileNotFoundException`, so they are found. I really don't understand what I'm doing wrong here. The Server can start up, the Client can start up, but when I call a remote method from Client to Server it crashes because of a failed handshake.

Comment: What is the result of the server side log I asked you to provide? And can you add to that -Djava.rmi.server.exceptionTrace? NB Failure to find these files causes exceptions, but not FileNotFoundException.

Comment: I got the following from the Server:
`sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef logCall
FINER: RMI TCP Connection(1)-127.0.0.1: [127.0.0.1: sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl[0:0:0, 0]: java.rmi.Remote lookup(java.lang.String)]`

Comment: Were there any exceptions shown? NB I asked to to edit this into your question. It isn't really legible as comments.